# Laravel relationships with three tables

Tags: laravel

I am busy building a online ordering system, but now I am stuck with this one table relationship.

I want the User to be able to create many orders, and the order will have many products.

I have looked at many-to-many relationships, however it does not include a third table.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The basic many-to-many relationship releases by pivot table and declares in laravel like `belongsToMany`

In your situation you can use `hasManyThgough` relationship to access all products which are connected with user through orders

`User.php`

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}

public function products() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Order');
}
```

`Order.php`

```
public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

[Link to laravel relationship hasManyThrough documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: Thank you. That looks as if it worked, how will the order and product tables look like? Order will have a user_id and the pivot table will have order_id and product_id?